# Can't seem to gobble up these nested images in jquery for event handling

Tags: jquery

Note: The version of jQuety I am working with does not support ".on". Also, I want the LI to be clickable.

Note: I did some additional testing and even capturing ALL Li's on the page, within the UL in question, none of the LI's will allow for delegate or live to work. I do not get it.

Basically I have a lot of list items, and there is no real way to grab these LI elemenets because there are no unique id's assigned. I could try to match on a "partial id", which I've tried.

The weird thing is, I am having success when NOT using ".live" or ".delegate". For example, if I use just ".bind"... I can get at them.

What is ODD: in some ".live" tries I can get all the elements. BUT, clicking on them does nothing. So, I see them in the basket (when I console them), but clicking on them does nothing.

I have a structure like so - the UL > LI are surrounded by many divs. (just to give you an idea that the data structure is very dense).

```
 <li id="item_111190897">
   <span class="shoeColor" style="display:none">Blue Converse</span>
   <span class="shoeColor">
      <a class="shoepopup" data-popup-ref="#shoe_item_111190897" href="javascript:;">
        <img class="available" src="/media/available.gif" alt="">
      </a>
      <span class="">
        <img alt="" src="shoeicon.png">
      </span>
    Blue Converse Available Now!
  </span>
```

basically, there are a bunch of these LI's - and with no discernable thing to hook onto, I am trying the following: ALL DO NOT WORK!!!

```
 $(document).delegate("li:has(.available)", "click", function(){
     // do something
 })

 $(document).delegate("li[id^='item_']", "click", function(){
     // do something
 })

 $(document).delegate(".available.closest('li')", "click", function(){
     // do something
 })


 $('li:has(.available)').live("click", function(){
     // do something
 })
```

tried alot more with permuations for ".live"...

BUT ---> ".bind" works. This works.

```
 $('li:has(.available)').bind("click", function(){
     // do something
 })
```

any advice?

Comment: Can you summarize in a line which `li` elements you want to select, or what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I wannt to put the "click" event on the LI -- I will update original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("li:has(.available)", "click", function(){
     // do something
 });
```

Edit: Based on your edited question, just replace `on` with `delegate`:

```
$(document).delegate("li:has(.available)", "click", function(){
     // do something
 });
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s82mr/) example.

You forgot the `.` before `available` class name.

Note: If you're using `jQuery` version greater than `1.7`, you should use `on`.

Comment: I should have mentioned this - can't use ".on", but contracting job I am at does not have the version that supports ".on" :-( , so I either have to go with .deletate or .live.

Comment: Let me review my updates - I believe me ommiting the "." was just a typing error in the OP. As I am fairly certain I covered with a find tooth comb in the actual code, but you never know. I also did more research and "forgot" that with ".live" there are some pitfalls that got me, so yeah - delegate should work. Let me review.